# Error while creating DataFrame with several lists and certain columns

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I try to create a pandas data frame using:

```
zeros = [0]*3
values = [10, 20, 30] # numpy array
index = ['D', 'E']
col = ['A', 'B', 'C']
df = pd.DataFrame([[zeros], [values]], index=index, columns=unique)
```

I want to receive

|  | A | B | C |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| D | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| E | 10 | 20 | 30 |

I get the following error:

```
3 columns passed, passed data had 1 columns
```

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

You were getting error because of passing `list of list` as elements of the dataframe. We can replace `[zeros], [values]]` with `[zeros, values]`.

We don't have to pass `list of list` for elements `[[zeros], [values]]` and `columns value` is to be passed from `col` variable.

**Code**

```
zeros = [0]*3
values = [10, 20, 30] # numpy array

index = ['D', 'E']
col = ['A', 'B', 'C']

df = pd.DataFrame([zeros, values], index=index, columns=col)
df
```

**Output**

```
    A   B   C
D   0   0   0
E   10  20  30
```

Comment: Oh, it was that simple) Thank you!

Comment: Nw, all the best!